# Replace not working as expected, razor engine inserting unwanted periods

Tags: c#, .net, razor, replace

I have a class that uses the razor engine to generate html templates and there seems to be an issue where some links (anchors or images) have an additional period inserted into the address, usually at the www. part making the link unusable.

There doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason as to when or where it does this, sometimes it works fine, other times several of the links have this issue.

So when I return the template as string to then send as an email I call replace like below:

```
var fixedTemplate = template.Replace("www..", "www.");
```

But this isn't working. I've never ran into this issue before. The strings are quite large, could this cause problems with the replace function?

How can I

a) Fix the razor engine so that these random periods are no longer added in links

Or

b) Find out why the replace function isn't replacing all of the occurrences.

A sample of the code called in my class below for completeness.

```
// nt = class associated with template     
using (TemplateService templateService = new TemplateService())
{
string html = templateService.Parse(File.ReadAllText(nt.TemplateFilePath), nt, null, null);

var pm = new PreMailer.Net.PreMailer(html);
//inline css styles with premailer    
Emailer.SendTestEmail(pm.MoveCssInline().Html, emailAddress, "Test Email: " + campaign.Title);
pm = null;
}
```

And the emailer code where replace is called

```
public static void SendTestEmail(string template, string emailAddress, string subject)
        {
            var updatedTemplate = template.Replace("www..", "www.");

            var email = new MailMessage
            {

                Body = updatedTemplate,
                Subject = subject,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                From = new MailAddress("noreply@mydomain.com")
            };
            email.To.Add(emailAddress);

            using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtpClient.PickupDirectoryLocation = "M:\\Pickup";
                smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                smtpClient.Send(email);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would suggest that if the Replace doesn't resolve the problem, then the problem is occurring _after_ the section of code which contains the Replace. Replace is well tested and copes with large strings (although it is probably not the most efficient way to replace text). Have you stepped through the code to see if the double dot "www.." is there before _and_ after the Replace?

Comment: Yes, just stepped through and replace is not replacing all occurrences, the doubles dots and there before and after. I'm very aware how tried and tested the replace function is but there's something here that's causing it to not work. Or I'm missing something. The code above is a direct copy and paste from my project, I've not simplified it, the only change is the domain name in the from mail address and the only thing that happens to the string after replace is it is assigned to the body property of the mail object.

Comment: Maybe it is not simply a double dot? Maybe there are hidden/special characters? If you copy and paste the "www.." directly from `template` and paste that into an _additional_ Replace, that might identify if the text is unusual. (Remember to copy the value from an instance of it failing.)

Comment: Also, are you certain that - when the Replace fails - you haven't received triple dots? `"www...".Replace("www..", "www.")` would result in `"www.."`.

Comment: Hi @Ulric, forcing encoding of the string to UTF8 seems to have resolved the problem!

Comment: Cool. Glad it now works. :)